# How to directly show a UIViewController when i receive a UIlocalnotification?

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uistoryboard, uilocalnotification

I am using Storyboard and this is a TabBarApplication. How i designed it is every tab has UINavigationController and then corresponding UIViewController.
Now when i receive a UILocalNotification i want to get to a particular view where i want to show this.

I am doing this in didReceiveLocalNotofication

```
if (!_tabBarController) {
    _tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)_window.rootViewController;
}

NSArray *notificationName = [notification.userInfo valueForKey:@"kDetails"];
NSString * identifer = [notificationName objectAtIndex:1];

NSArray * vcs = [_tabBarController viewControllers];
UINavigationController * listVC = [vcs lastObject];
NSArray * array = [listVC viewControllers];

ListViewController * contacts = [array lastObject];
DetailsViewController * details = [[DetailsViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"DetailsViewController" bundle:nil];
contacts.navigationItem.title = @"Details";

details.dataSet = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[PersistData sharedData].completeData];
for (int i=0; i<[details.dataSet count]; i++) {
    DataType * wid = [details.dataSet objectAtIndex:i];
    if ([wid.identifier isEqualToString:identifer]) {
            // This is the meeting
        details.index = i;
    }
    [contacts.navigationController pushViewController:details animated:YES];
}

notification.fireDate = nil;
```

But this is not displaying the required view.

Comment: Not yet.This will only land me up to the Tab in which i want to go but i still need to go further in to the specific controller.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set you current selected tabBarController.

```
[_tabBarController setSelectedIndex:indexOfLastTabItem];
```

Comment: The view controller i am trying to get to is the one which was pushed over the one which will be showed with above code.

Comment: but you have to wrote this line to use selected index over tabbarcontroller

Comment: And make sure that you have something in vcs.